R function for rearranging my data for quick plotting with facet wrap
Trying to teach myself R for data visualization purposes and struggling with very basic problems but unable to find questions that answer this! If it's been answered before, providing a link to the questions work too thank you!!
Not sure if there's a better way to automate my data preparation process such that I can skip the step of manually copying and pasting my data into a format that my r code can plot into a combined graph using facet wrap quickly!
An example of the problem I'm facing!
How my data is generated: (https://i.sstatic.net/gJukMCIz.png)
What I have to do: (https://i.sstatic.net/IYVAgn5W.png)
To get: (https://i.sstatic.net/ykvaP9u0.png)
My current code:
ggplot(data=flower,aes(x=group,y=# of flowers,fill=group))+geom_boxplot()+ facet_wrap(~colour)+labs(x=NULL)

That operation is usually referred to as reshaping or pivoting(longer), take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format , if your leaning towards Tidyverse, you might want to focus on answers that are using tidyr::pivot_longer()

Welcome to StackOverflow, kaizzo bean! You can help the community to help you by reading and following this basic advice.
